# how to calculate the nearest location to locations in excel sheet from another locations un another excel sheet using Lat and Long using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, python-2.7

i'm trying to calculate the nearest location from group of data to other group of data from excel sheets so far that's what I wrote, however I'm troubled with the below issue:

```
  File "C:\Users\mohamed.h.mohamad\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 19, in dist
    lat1, long1, lat2, long2 = map(radians, [lat1, long1, lat2, long2])

TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

I don't know were I go wrong as I already turned the Lat and Long to Float64 however that's not the problem

```
import pandas as pd
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
Sites = pd.read_excel("E:\Request/site.xlsx")
Sites.head()
Complaint = pd.read_excel("E:\Request/complaints.xlsx")
Complaint.head()
Sites['lat'].astype(dtype = 'float64')
Sites['long'].astype(dtype = 'float64')
Complaint['lat'].astype(dtype = 'float64')
Complaint['long'].astype(dtype = 'float64')
def dist(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lat1, long1, lat2, long2 = map(radians, [lat1, long1, lat2, long2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = long2 - long1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    # Radius of earth in kilometers is 6371
    km = 6371* c
    return km

def find_nearest(lat, long):
    distances = Sites.apply(
        lambda row: dist(lat, long, row['lat'], row['long']), 
        axis=1)
    return Sites.loc[distances.idxmin(), 'Site']
Complaint['Site'] = Complaint.apply(
    lambda row: find_nearest(row['lat'], row['long']), 
    axis=1)
# To check the data frame if it has a new column of hotel name (for each and every member's location in the list)
Complaint.head()
Complaint = pd.merge(Complaint,Sites[['Site','lat','lon']],on='Site', how='left')
# Rename the new columns as both the columns has same name, and python gets confused 
Complaint=Complaint.rename(columns = {'lat_x':'m_lat','lon_x':'m_lon','lat_y':'h_lat','lon_y':'h_lon'})
Complaint.head()

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    # Radius of earth in kilometers is 6371
    km = 6371* c
    return km
# Creating a new column to generate the output by passing lat long information to Haversine Equation
Complaint['distance'] = [haversine(Complaint.m_lon[i],Complaint.m_lat[i],Complaint.h_lon[i],Complaint.h_lat[i]) for i in range(len(Complaint))]
Complaint['distance'] = Complaint['distance'].round(decimals=3)
# Printing the data table 
Complaint.head()
Complaint.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

so can any one help me to solve this issue
thanks in advance

Comment: I created `site.xlsx` and `complaints.xlsx` documents with one row and `lat`, `long`, `Site` columns. `dist` method works. Perhaps, the problem is in your input data.

Comment: here is a sample of my data
Sites lat long
1341643 30.003631  31.318165
1342118 29.987926  31.25709
1342396 30.165714  31.320662
1344621 29.890962 31.293879
1345452 30.001362 31.165066